# C# check if a Label is completely visible

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Is there a way to check if the text associated with a multiline label is completely visible?
This is necessary for me to change font size in the case label is too small to let all text be visible.

Comment: WinForm, WPF, AS.NET?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working in winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mess around with this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
  label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
  //First make the font big enough
  double fontSize = label1.Width / label1.Text.Count();
  int height = label1.Height;
  fontSize = fontSize > 0 ? (double)fontSize : 1;
  if (fontSize < (height / 2))
  {
    fontSize = (height / 2);
  }
  label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, (float)fontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

  //then adjust the text to the label size
  while (label1.Width < System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(label1.Text,
      new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size, label1.Font.Style)).Width ||
      label1.Height < System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(label1.Text,
      new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size, label1.Font.Style)).Height)
  {
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size > 1 ? label1.Font.Size - 0.5f : label1.Font.Size, label1.Font.Style);
    if (label1.ClientRectangle.Width < 3 || label1.ClientRectangle.Height < 3)
      break;
  }
}
```

It will use the text of textBox1 to fill the label, and based on the contents, will adjust the font size to the label.